# Codeigniter adds index.php to a download url

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, iframe

I am trying to make a button that when pressed calls a javascript function that downloads a file.

download code:

```
function downloadFile(url)
{
   console.log('Clicked');
   var iframe;
   iframe = document.getElementById("download-container");
   if (iframe === null)
   {
       iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
       iframe.id = "download-container";
       iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       document.body.appendChild(iframe);
   }
   iframe.src = "uploads/img/"+url;   
}
```

button code:

```
<?php echo '<button type="button" onclick="downloadFile(\''.$value.'\')">'.$value.'</button>' ?>
```

the output is:

```
GET http://localhost/dfi/index.php/uploads/img/Mux.png 404 (Not Found)
```

because index.php is added to the url, when i remove index.php and access the file directly in the browser i can access it normally.

Comment: have you got a htaccess in main directory and removed index.php from config.php file?

Comment: Yes i have an htaccess and i removed the index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
iframe.src = "/uploads/img/"+url;
```

Or add the full url to the src :

```
iframe.src = "http://localhost/dfi/uploads/img/"+url;
```

Comment: It didn't download using the full link, also i can't use the full url as this will be uploaded to a server later so i don't like to use full url.

Comment: Did it work with the absolute path? If not, was it the same issue?